# How to parse user agent string using regular expression?

Tags: java, regex, browser

I want "OS ,  Device , Manufacturer" details from the user agent string. But , nowadays the useragent string format  is not standard by browsers as mentioned in the link https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.43.

I analyzed couple of thirdparties like ua-parser. What I feel is if any new browsers or device is launched. I need to wait for their release or change the source code.

How can I extract the details?

Is there any regex to find the details?

Comment: How about searching for an answer before you ask?  If I can Google it, so can you ...

Comment: @StephenC , I surfed google. Many third parties are there for parsing user agent. They all are predefined. Example : If  "Nokia" launches new smart phone. I need to add this in my code.